# Proper way to reference multiple objects while inserting in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am working on a .Net blog style API as a practice project and have come across a road block. I have a User class, Post class and Comment class. Comment has reference to both Post and User, each one-to-many.

Here is my User class:

```
 public class User
    {
        //Other properties..
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

My Post class:

```
public class Post
    {
        //Other properties..
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

and my Comment class:

```
  public class Comment
    {
        //Other properties..
        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

I am attempting to save a comment like this

```
commentToAdd.Post = new Post
{
    Id = id //getting the id from url
};
commentToAdd.CreatedBy = new User
{
    Id = currentUser //getting the id from the JWT token
};
 await _context.Comments.AddAsync(comment);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It seems doing this, it's attempting to insert into both the User and Post table. I have tried looking up solutions but I haven't really been able to find anything that quite matches this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create `new post() and` new User(). if you have Ids of user and post. you can either fetch them from db.

```
commenttoadd.post = _context.post.firstordefault(s=>s.Id == postid) //same for User
```

or alternatively you can add userid and postid properties

```
 public class Comment
    {
        public <yourIdDataType> UserId {get;set;}
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public <yourpostidDataType> PostId{get;set;}
        public Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

and then directly assign these userid and postid to them. in that case you dont need to fetch user and post from db.

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't construct an object to use an existing entity, you retrieve the one that already exists.

```
commentToAdd.Post = new Post
{
    Id = id //getting the id from url
};
commentToAdd.CreatedBy = _context.Users.Find(currentUser); //getting the id from the JWT token
await _context.Comments.AddAsync(commentToAdd);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```